# Transpose Dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have `dataframe` like below.

```
+---+------+------+
| ID|Field1|Field2|
+---+------+------+
|  1|     x|     n|
|  2|     a|     b|
+---+------+------+
```

And I need the output like below

```
+---+-------------+------+
| ID|       Fields|values|
+---+-------------+------+
|  1|Field1,Field2|   x,n|
|  2|Field1,Field2|   a,b|
+---+-------------+------+
```

I am pretty new to scala..  I just need an approach to do this.  I already researched on internet regarding transpose, but couldn't get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Fields` column is going to be the same in every row, you can add it later.

In this example class Thing has 3 fields: id, Field1, Field2.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext( sc )
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = 
    sc
    .parallelize( List( Thing( 1, "a", "b" ), Thing( 2, "x", "y" ) ) )
    .toDF( "id", "Field1", "Field2" )
```

Column names are returned in the same order so we can just take last two for field names

```
val fieldNames = 
    df
    .columns
    .takeRight( 2 )
```

The `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` does all the job combining data from given columns.

```
val res = 
    df
    .select( $"id", array( $"Field1", $"Field2" ) as "values" )
    .withColumn( "Fields", lit( fieldNames ) )

res.show()
```

Result:

```
+---+------+----------------+
| id|values|          Fields|
+---+------+----------------+
|  1|[a, b]|[Field1, Field2]|
|  2|[x, y]|[Field1, Field2]|
+---+------+----------------+
```